# Session value to array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I have this function that save data after the button is clicked.

```
 $data=$_POST;
    $details = array();
    $details['title'] = $data['title'];
    $details['content'] = $data['text'];
    $details['snippet'] = $data['hidden_snippet'];
  $details['createdDate']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $result=$this->ask_model->book_add($details);
```

I want to add the session value which contains the user id from another table in a column named "author_id" .

```
$data= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
```

I tried to do this but the value I'm getting is null.

```
$data= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
  $data=$_POST;
    $details = array();
    $details['title'] = $data['title'];
    $details['content'] = $data['text'];
    $details['snippet'] = $data['hidden_snippet'];
  $details['createdDate']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $details['author_id']= $data;
    $result=$this->ask_model->book_add($details);
```

Here's the error:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZlFt.png)

What do I need to convert the session value into so I could add it to the array?

**Update:**

OK I'm a beginner at CodeIgniter and this problem is because of my own stupidity. The model I used was not set on $autoload['model']  on autoload.php plus I've been calling the wrong url in my ajax at my view file. The comments does solve one of my problem so thank you so much!

Comment: You're overwriting `$data= $this->session->userdata('user_id');` in the very next line with `$data=$_POST;`. You should probably just change `$details['author_id']= $data;` to `$details['author_id']= $this->session->userdata('user_id');`

Comment: @Nick I'm still getting the same results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are replacing data unnecessarily. This way I think you should do it

```
$user_id= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$data=$_POST;
    $details = array();
    $details['title'] = $data['title'];
    $details['content'] = $data['text'];
    $details['snippet'] = $data['hidden_snippet'];
  $details['createdDate']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $details['author_id']= $user_id;


$result=$this->ask_model->book_add($details);
```

Answer (score 0):

First load model in `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Ask_model');
```

Make sure the first letter of file and class name should be capitalized. It should be `Ask_model` not `ask_model`

`$data = $_POST` overwriting the value of `$this->session->userdata('user_id')` because you are also giving the same variable name.

Overwriting here

```
$data= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$data=$_POST;
```

Do like this

```
$author_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$data=$_POST;
$details = array();
$details['title'] = $data['title'];
$details['content'] = $data['text'];
$details['snippet'] = $data['hidden_snippet'];
$details['createdDate']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$details['author_id']= $author_id ;
$result=$this->ask_model->book_add($details);
```